# WebApi2 Owin Claims Application Cookie

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies, owin

I have an SPA app built with AngularJS, the backend is WebApi2. I´m struggling with Authentication and Authorization. What I want in the long run is to enable authentication against Active Directory. But for now, I just trying to enable authorization for my APiControllers and setting a Cookie with Owin.

Here is my Owin Identity Helper class, I´m only adding 1 claim that is the serialized user info:

```
public void SignIn(bool rememberMe, T user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)),
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = rememberMe }, claimsIdentity);
    }
```

Here is authentication in controller:

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("authenticate")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate()
    {
        var authenticated = IdentityContext.Current.IsAuthenticated;

        if (!authenticated)
        {
            var user = new User();
            user.Email = "roger@moore.com";
            user.Name = "Roger Moore";
            user.Id = 23;

            IdentityContext.Current.SignIn(true, user);

            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user),
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json"
                )
            };
        }
        else
        {
            //return the user if authenticated
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(
                   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IdentityContext.Current.User), //from claim
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json"
                )
            };
        }
    }
```

My StartUp class

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/signedout")
        });
    }
}
```

When I call the authenticate user I´m setting signing in, but when calling a controller with [Authorize] attribute, im not signed in. Furthermore, when having fiddler running I get the error: 
"[Fiddler] Response Header parsing failed. This can be caused by an illegal HTTP response earlier on this reused server socket-- for instance, a HTTP/304 response which illegally contains a body. Response Data:"

Does anyone have any suggestions, or alternatives with example code for using JWT Token Authentication and Authorization From Angular to WebApi2?

Comment: Have you looked into the SPA template of VS2013? Authentication is done by sending a OAuth bearer token which is more secure than cookies since it prevents CSRF

Comment: No I have not. Good idea. I'll do that post my findings...